# Can the My Domain feature support multiple domains

Tags: hierarchy, mydomain

Salesforce Org has two companies using it - where one is a wholly owned subsidiary of the other. We now need to enable My Domain for Lightning components to work and have a business request that we have a different domain name for each of the two companies in the same SF org, e.g. company1-my-salesforce.com and childcompany.my.salesforce.com with users distinguished by profile and/or role.

Looking at the documentaion and setup page it appears that a maximum number of 1 domiain is supported for login of internal users on the full Salesforce lenience. Is there any meanse of working around this?

Comment: Looks like you're going to need to choose between a common domain and an org split.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I suspect it would need to come down to that, I wonder if just using separate branding once the users are logged in might resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your only option if you want to support multiple domains is an org split. It doesn't seem like a feature they can easily relax the limit on. You can use `Salesforce2Salesforce` if you need to sync data between the orgs.

An org split might be a bit heavy-handed, depending on your end goal. It's still unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish. You might consider using `Profiles` specific  to each company, and then changing layouts, etc. based on them.

Comment: This seems like the way to go.  Then you can do custom App Assignments to each profile with their own branding and look and feel.